# Add Trim/Bleed Marks to PDF - PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I'm attempting to add [trim/bleed marks](http://www.theprintgroup.com.au/graphic-design/what-are-crop-marks-and-bleed.html) to a PDF using [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)

I can set the top left hand corner of the PDF, however all other corners are not showing,

What I am doing is setting the `xGraphics.DrawLine` to the position of the top left, adding the bleed marks for both the top left and top left bottom and then I am rotating the PDF's page so that the same `xGraphics.DrawLine` positions can be used, 
so that if the PDF's pages size was different, I'm hoping because its the top left, it would always have the correct bleed mark position.
Below is the method I have created as well as the result.
I also tried putting `using (XGraphics xGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage))` within `for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)` hoping it would reload the pdf page with the changes as the first loop seems to be ok, however there was no change.

```
/// <summary>
/// Add Bleed To PDF.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pdfDocument"></param>
static void AddBleed(ref PdfDocument pdfDocument)
{
    // Check The Pdf Has Been Loaded Into Memory.
    if (pdfDocument.PageCount > 0)
    {
        // Create Pen.
        XPen xPen = new XPen(XColors.Gray, 3);
        const float TRIM_MARK_LEN = 30;

        // Start Looping The Pdf's Pages
        foreach (PdfPage pdfPage in pdfDocument.Pages)
        {
            using (XGraphics xGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage))
            {                     
                // A Page Has 4 Sides.
                for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
                {
                    // Top Left.
                    xGraphics.DrawLine(xPen, TRIM_MARK_LEN, TRIM_MARK_LEN - 10, TRIM_MARK_LEN, -10);

                    // Bottom Top Left.
                    xGraphics.DrawLine(xPen, 0, TRIM_MARK_LEN, TRIM_MARK_LEN - 10, TRIM_MARK_LEN);

                    // Rotate The Pdf Page.
                    xGraphics.PdfPage.Rotate = xGraphics.PdfPage.Rotate + 90;

                    // Save The Graphics.
                    xGraphics.Save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you have to create a new XGraphics object after changing the rotation of the page.

You want to draw four angles, one in each corner. But AFAIK your code will draw four angles at the same position as the co-ordinates rotate with the page.

Stop rotating the page and draw the four angles separately.

BTW: Calling `Save()` only makes sense when you call `Restore()` later on. The invocation of `Save()` in your code has no visual effect as far as I can tell. Better drop that line.

Comment: I was hoping I could rotate it as I was having trouble getting all other corners, however thanks for clearing up that that won’t work as I intended.